# Split line in data file

Tags: python, split

I'm struggling with splitting lines in my data file. Here is a few lines sample:

```
1:0 2:120
1:1 2:131
1:2 2:26
1:3 2:568
1:4 2:176
1:5 2:28 3:549
1:6 2:17
1:7 2:6 3:217 4:401 5:636
1:8 2:139
```

I want to split it to get out each value ... maybe in form of an array:

```
((1, 2) , (0, 120))
((1, 2) , (1, 131))
...
((1, 2, 3, 4, 5) , (7, 6, 217, 401, 636))
```

meaning that for each line the array could have different dimensions. 
I was trying to split it in two steps, but it doesn't work.

```
inf = open("datafile.txt", 'r')

for line in inf: 
line.split()
for x in line.split():
    x.split(':',1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can group the elements of two lists, using [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) function.

```
with open("Input.txt") as inf:
    for line in inf:
        print zip(*map(lambda x: map(int, x.split(":")), line.split()))
```

**Output**

```
[(1, 2), (0, 120)]
[(1, 2), (1, 131)]
[(1, 2), (2, 26)]
[(1, 2), (3, 568)]
[(1, 2), (4, 176)]
[(1, 2, 3), (5, 28, 549)]
[(1, 2), (6, 17)]
[(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (7, 6, 217, 401, 636)]
[(1, 2), (8, 139)]
```

**Suggestion :**
It is always good to open the files with `with` keyword, like I have shown in the code above. Because, it will take care of closing/releasing the resources, even if the program fails with an exception.

**Explanation:**

Since `zip` is a function call, the parameters are evaluated first. Lets come to the `*` later. `map(lambda x: map(int, x.split(":")), line.split())`, we apply the lambda function `lambda x: map(int, x.split(":"))` to each and every element of the list of strings returned by `line.split()` (which splits the sentences at whitespace characters and returns the list).

Each and every split word, will be passed as parameter to the lambda function one by one. If we take the first case, first `"1:0"` will be sent to the lambda function as `x`, where we split based on `:` which will give a list `["1", "0"]` and then we apply `int` function over that, which will give `[1, 0]`. So, after all the lines are split and lambda is applied, the result will be like this

```
[[1, 0], [2, 120]]
[[1, 1], [2, 131]]
[[1, 2], [2, 26]]
[[1, 3], [2, 568]]
[[1, 4], [2, 176]]
[[1, 5], [2, 28], [3, 549]]
[[1, 6], [2, 17]]
[[1, 7], [2, 6], [3, 217], [4, 401], [5, 636]]
[[1, 8], [2, 139]]
```

Now we have two elements in each list. Remember the `*` which we decided to discuss later, it will unpack the list and pass all the elements as parameters to the `zip` function, like this

```
zip([1, 0], [2, 120])
```

Now `zip` will pick all the first elements and put them in a list, and then it will pick all the second elements and put them in a list and so on.

This is how we get the answer you expected.

Comment: Thanks a lot, works correctly now. I'm only beginner in python. Could you please give me a quick comment on zip, *map and lambda?

Comment: @user3041107 Please check the updated answer now. I have added a little explanation.

Comment: thanks it is very clear now. one more thing - how can I access those values? If I want eg. access value [1, 2] = 217 on the 8th line of the data.

Comment: I see, I can just make c = np.array() of the whole zip and then it is possible

Comment: @user3041107 I am sorry, I don't know `numpy` :( and I believe my answer best matches your question.